# Bugzilla Installation + Windows 7 + sendmail

Tags: windows, localhost, bugzilla

We have installed a Bugzila 4.0 on Windows 7 Local Machine. After the installation we are not able to create any New Account as the New Account sends a email to the email id being provided for the user. So we installed Sendmail for Windows and configured bugzilla to use Sendmail for sending mails via bugzilla. Now whenever we are trying to send emails via bugzilla on new account creation we are getting below mentioned error:

"error when closing pipe to /usr/lib/sendmail.exe: Inappropriate I/O control operation"

Request you to please guide us if we are missing any configuration on Bugzilla or if there is any other workaround to send mail via bugzilla on local machine.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Vineet More

Answer (score 0):

Are you using http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/ ?

If answer is yes, I think you should also download and install: https://metacpan.org/pod/App::TLSMe

Try to run your checksetup.pl to see if need any other prerequisite.